# Как получить $(this).text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня генерируются след. элементы:

```
<li onclick='SetSearchValue()'>".$data['name']."</li>
```

Я хочу в функции SetSearchValue получить текстовое значение li

```
function SetSearchValue()
{
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
}
```

Как это сделать?

**P.S. Только без передачи параметра в функцию.**

Comment: Непонятно в каком контексте эта функция будет вызываться и почему без передачи параметров? Приведите пример ожидаемого поведения и пример кода который не работает

Comment: Получить значение или текст можно либо повесив обработчик, либо вызвав функцию и передав ей параметр. Как по другому? Это как если написать не с чем не связанную функцию и удивляться почему она не выполняет операции о которых я думаю в голове. Код не читает мысли, он делает то что ему говорят.

Comment: В данный момент выполнение представленной мною функции выводит в консоль: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: @DzianisSadouski По другому это через this. В функцию передается обьект который вызывает функцию. И в this на него ссылка. Почему тогда через this.find("div").text() к примеру, я могу взять текст если бы в li был вложен div? И не надо мне параметров передавать и обработчики вешать!

Comment: вот именно передавать все равно придется)) не важно что, сам факт! Я имел ввиду что оставив скобки пустыми ты ничего не добьешься.

Comment: Ну или конечно ты можешь вызывать функцию и из нее напрямую обращаться к элементу по классу или id. Но это не рационально, лично мое мнение.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру так

```js
$('li.li_test').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).text())
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="li_test">любой текст</li>
<li class="li_test">другой текст</li>
<li>Не активный LI</li>
```

Вот ваш вариант

```js
function SetSearchValue(e)
{
    var text = $(e).text();
    console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li onclick='SetSearchValue(this)'>текст</li>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Кажется то что нужно. Первый вариант представленный не универсальный, так как на странице много списков. Второй видимо явно через передачу параметра this

Comment: Однако в конкретно моем случае я получаю в консоле:
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost:3000"; from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Что это может быть?

Comment: Вы выполняете post запрос, на локальной машине со ссылкой на себя, это и есть ошибка. Не связано. А за первый случай, как сделал я, можно навесить класс на li и отрабатывать по нему. Добавил class `li_test`

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(this).text();
```

Не работает так?

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: а что возвращает 
alert($(this).text())


alert($(this))


alert(this)